# Creating a Windows 10 Installation Media USB

Tags: windows, windows-10, bootable-media

I'm trying to re-install Windows 10 on a new harddrive in my PC.

Steps so far  :

- I downloaded the Windows 10 installer that builds a mountable USB.
- I then replaced the harddrives in the Windows PC with a new SSD.
- As part of this I also had to disconnect the CD Drive because of cabling requirements
- Where it all went wrong is that now when I try and boot from my Windows 10 USB, it doesn't recognise that USB.
- However it does recognise other USB sticks that I own aswell as my external harddrive.

Now my problems is this.

- All other USB sticks that I own are less than 4GB in size so they are of no use.
- My external harddrive has documents on it that I don't want to lose, so wiping it isn't on the table.
- I am typing this from a Mac book Pro.

Is there any way to take what was on the USB stick that doesn't work (A bunch of windows files it seems, it isn't a single ISO. Again I created this from the official installer package), and put them onto the external harddrive to boot from, without losing any files and doing this all from a macbook.

I tried a straight copy of the files, but once the post screen loads I get a flashing underscore which seems to indicate the external harddrive isn't bootable.

Comment: Are you saying the USB does not show up as a bootable device?  Edit your question,  If you had a Windows installation, I would just suggest using Rufus, and recreating the bootable disk yourself using the current Version 1607 ISO from Microsoft.

Comment: So I CAN boot from a USB drive, Just not the one that I happen to have the windows installation on. If I use any other USB drive and go to the boot menu in Bios, I can see the USB drive.

Comment: Clarification: You are installing Windows on a PC or on the Macbook?  If its the Macbook the you have to use EFI bootable disk which is what you have created.  If its a PC you either have to configure the PC to boot to that disk or make a MBR bootable disk instead, which is possible, but based on the information you provide its not clear what your attempting to do.

Comment: I am installing on a windows PC. However I am typing this from a mac. The reason I say that is that many guides often talk about how to make a USB drive bootable... but from the windows command prompt.